# Scala PartialFunction can be Monoid?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, partialfunction, monoids

I thought [PartialFunction](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.1/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala) can be [Monoid](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v6.0.4/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monoid.scala). Is my thought process correct ?
For example,

```scala
import scalaz._
import scala.{PartialFunction => -->}

implicit def partialFunctionSemigroup[A,B]:Semigroup[A-->B] = new Semigroup[A-->B]{
  def append(s1: A-->B, s2: => A-->B): A-->B = s1.orElse(s2)
}

implicit def partialFunctionZero[A,B]:Zero[A-->B] = new Zero[A-->B]{
  val zero = new (A-->B){
    def isDefinedAt(a:A) = false
    def apply(a:A) = sys.error("error")
  }
}
```

But current version Scalaz(6.0.4) is not included it.  Is there a reason for something not included ?

Comment: I assume you are aware that `Function1` is a monoid under composition?

Comment: @dcsobral `Function1[A, A]`, aka `Endo[A]`, is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's shine a different light on this.

`PartialFunction[A, B]` is isomorphic to `A => Option[B]`. (Actually, to be able to check if it is defined for a given `A` without triggering evaluation of the `B`, you would need `A => LazyOption[B]`)

So if we can find a `Monoid[A => Option[B]]` we've proved your assertion.

Given `Monoid[Z]`, we can form `Monoid[A => Z]` as follows:

```
implicit def readerMonoid[Z: Monoid] = new Monoid[A => Z] {
   def zero = (a: A) => Monoid[Z].zero
   def append(f1: A => Z, f2: => A => Z) = (a: A) => Monoid[Z].append(f1(a), f2(a))
}
```

So, what Monoid(s) do we have if we use `Option[B]` as our `Z`? Scalaz provides three. The primary instance requires a `Semigroup[B]`.

```
implicit def optionMonoid[B: Semigroup] = new Monoid[Option[B]] {
  def zero = None
  def append(o1: Option[B], o2: => Option[B]) = o1 match {
    case Some(b1) => o2 match {
       case Some(b2) => Some(Semigroup[B].append(b1, b2)))
       case None => Some(b1)
    case None => o2 match {
       case Some(b2) => Some(b2)
       case None => None
    }
  }
}
```

Using this:

```
scala> Monoid[Option[Int]].append(Some(1), Some(2))
res9: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

But that's not the only way to combine two Options. Rather than appending the contents of the two options in the case they are both `Some`, we could simply pick the first or the last of the two. Two trigger this, we create a distinct type with trick called Tagged Types. This is similar in spirit to Haskell's `newtype`.

```
scala> import Tags._
import Tags._

scala> Monoid[Option[Int] @@ First].append(Tag(Some(1)), Tag(Some(2)))
res10: scalaz.package.@@[Option[Int],scalaz.Tags.First] = Some(1)

scala> Monoid[Option[Int] @@ Last].append(Tag(Some(1)), Tag(Some(2)))
res11: scalaz.package.@@[Option[Int],scalaz.Tags.Last] = Some(2)
```

`Option[A] @@ First`, appended through it's `Monoid`, uses the same `orElse` semantics as your example.

So, putting this all together:

```
scala> Monoid[A => Option[B] @@ First]
res12: scalaz.Monoid[A => scalaz.package.@@[Option[B],scalaz.Tags.First]] = 
       scalaz.std.FunctionInstances0$$anon$13@7e71732c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I hadn't realized that PartialFunction is isomorphic to A => LazyOption[B]

Comment: Thanks, @retronym! Tagged Types are available only in scalaz-seven, for previous version it's necessary to use FirstOption trait, am I right?

Comment: @lester yep, exactly. Tagged Types have a few sharp edges, unfortunately, we might need better scalac support before we recommend them. Example is: `List(Tag(1))` gives a `ClassCastException` as one part of the compiler treats the arguments as an object array, and a later part as a primitive array.

Answer (score 2):

No, this looks good, satisfying both the requirements for (non-commutative) Monoid.   Interesting idea.  What use case are you trying to support?

Comment: @Heiko Sorry, but your statement is clearly wrong. Even if the answer is wrong it is far from clear (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

Your zero certainly violates the axiom for the identity element, but I think the identity (partial) function would be OK.

Your append also doesn't fulfill the Monoid laws, but instead of *orElse* you could call *andThen* (composition). But this would only work for A == B:

```
implicit def partialFunctionSemigroup[A]: Semigroup[A --> A] = new Semigroup[A --> A] {
  def append(s1: A --> A, s2: => A --> A): A-->A = s1 andThen s2
}

implicit def partialFunctionZero[A]: Zero[A --> A] = new Zero[A --> A] {
  val zero = new (A --> A) {
    def isDefinedAt(a:A) = true
    def apply(a:A) = a
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a counter-example?

Comment: For which `e` and `a` is it violated?

Comment: Your version is a monoid. The version of the OP is a monoid too.

Comment: Shame on me: I thought that throwing an exception would violate identity, but as isDefined will return false this is not the case.

Comment: `(S1 orElse zero) == (zero orElse S1) == S1`, so what's being violated about it? If `S1` is defined, then the result is `S1`. If `S1` is `zero` (ie, not defined), the result is `zero`.